# Exception in integration of banking api

Tags: java, php, exception

This is an exception referred to me for checking. This exception was raised when doing an API integration of ICICI bank.

> java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new
>   com.opus.epg.sfa.java.BillToAddress

reference URL: http://kndexim.com/java/SFAClient/TestPages/TestSsl.php

I am basically a J2EE developer, i do know only a little bit about php and . I know this is related to some class path problems. can i get a solution for this. If my question is not clear, please ask i will provide more details.

content of web.xml file is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <!-- support for Java EE cluster, remove this line if you want to put non-serializable objects into the java_session() -->
    <distributable/>

    <!-- Your system PHP executable. Default is /usr/bin/php-cgi or c:/Program Files/PHP/php-cgi.exe -->  
    <!--<context-param><param-name>php_exec</param-name><param-value>php-cgi</param-value></context-param>-->
    <!-- Prefer a system PHP executable, if available. Otherwise use the PHP from the .war file. Default is Off -->
    <context-param><param-name>prefer_system_php_exec</param-name><param-value>On</param-value></context-param>

    <!-- Handle PHP urls which cannot be expressed using a standard servlet spec 2.2 url-pattern, 
         e.g.: *.php/delete/from?what=that You may remove this and the filter-mapping below -->
    <filter><filter-name>PhpCGIFilter</filter-name><filter-class>php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter</filter-class></filter>
    <filter-mapping><filter-name>PhpCGIFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>

    <!-- Attach the JSR223 script factory to the servlet context -->
    <listener><listener-class>php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>

    <!-- PHP Servlet: back-end for Apache or IIS -->
    <servlet><servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet</servlet-class></servlet>

    <!-- PHP CGI servlet: when IIS or Apache are not available -->
    <servlet><servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet</servlet-class></servlet>

    <!-- PHP Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.phpjavabridge</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>

    <!-- PHP CGI Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Welcome files -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Should servlet.jar,servlet-api.jar included?

Answer (score 0):

There is a ClassNotFoundException. Typical cause is jar missing.

Try looking for this class com.opus.epg.sfa.java.BillToAddress and include the class/jar in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The WebappClassLoader does not have the class, `com.opus.epg.sfa.java.BillToAddress`, defined within it.

You should make sure the jar containing the class is included in the classpath, and once you do so, use `java_require('someJar.jar')` to include it into your classpath.